# Using HTML to implement Python User Interface

Tags: python, html, user-interface

I've just started learning a bit of Python and I'm currently trying to implement a Python UI through HTML. Is there anything in vanilla Python that would allow for this, similar to how you can create UI's with Java and XML with JFX or will I have to use a framework such as Django?

I'm reluctant to use Django as there are many features that I do not need

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vanilla python [wsgiref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html) is very helpful for building the server-side of web-applications (possibly with [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) and/or [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)) but if you want it more direct communication I would suggest [XML-RPC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.html) (there are good js-clients out there).

It is also possible to execute Python Scripts right in your Website with [Brython](http://www.brython.info/) or (with strong constraints) [Ironpython](http://ironpython.net/)

For Windows you can build [HTML Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) with [Ironpython](http://ironpython.net/) (have not tried but in theory it should work) or [Brython](http://www.brython.info/) (if you dont want to require the user to have ironpython installed)

You can also use [Pyjs](http://pyjs.org/) to build applications but while it uses html and javascript, i think it you dont see much of it.

There are HTML things in some ui-libraries like in [wxpython](https://wxpython.org/) (I am quite sure you will find them in many libraries)